# Invalid Template (dojo _HasDropDown)

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to write a new Widget which works with two *DIV* Tags one outer DIV and one inner DIV. And if the user clicks on the inner *DIV* than there shall pop up a DropDownlist which options will be gotten by a SQLite Database.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare","dijit/_Widget", "dijit/_Templated","dojo/_base/lang","dojo/request/xhr", "dojox/form/DropDownSelect"],function(declare,_Widget,_Templated,lang,xhr,DropDownSelect){
    return declare([_Widget,_Templated],{
        label : "Test PopUp",       
        templateString : null,
        savedData : [],
        datab : null,
        constructor : function(db){
            this.datab = db;
            xhr("getoptions.php?database="+db+"&order=read").then(lang.hitch(this,function(result){this.createTS(result.toString().split(";"))}));
            //this.templateString = TString;
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        //TemplateString will be created
        createTS : function(str){
            var tmpdiv = document.createElement("div")
            tmpdiv.innerHTML += "<div data-dojo-type='dojox/form/DropDownSelect'>";
            for(var i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
                var span = '<span id="'+i+'">'+str[i]+'</span>';
                tmpdiv.innerHTML += span;
            }
            tmpdiv.innerHTML += "</div>";
            var cont = document.createElement("div");
            cont.appendChild(tmpdiv);
            templateString = cont.innerHTML;
        },
        onChange : function(value){
            this.savedData.push(value.toString());
        },
    });
});
```

Firebug is telling me that the template is invalid.

The Widget code is here:
http://pastebin.com/LQk7iFkH

How shall the string look alike to work properly?

Greetings

Comment: Have you tried creating the template as a seperate html file and then loading it into the widget?

Comment: Use `dojo/text!` to load an html file with your widget definition then set the `templateString` to the file's contents. It's better than building the markup in code.

Comment: then I could make the getoptions.php to create the HTML?

Comment: see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/text.html for usage

Comment: It's asynchronous code, your createTS function will not be called before your constructors finish running.